# Is there a way to stop the form moving?

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

Once the validation has passed, the textboxes move, i think this is where the absence of the errors being displayed, it has automatically moved into the free space. Is there a way around this specifically through Javascript, html, or css?

css

```
.error{
     visibility: hidden;
     color: #FF2121;
 }
```

Html

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>RATool</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cfcss.css">
   <script src="cf.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1> Zedland Health Authority </h1>
    <h2> Contact Form </h2>
       <fieldset>
          <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input name="fname" id="fname" class="formfield" type="text">
               <span id="errfname" class="error">*This is required</span>
               <span id="errfname1" class="error">*Name fields must have more than one character, and do not contain numbers
                    or other non-allowed alphabetic characters. The only character the last name
                    field should legitimately contain is a hyphen (e.g. Whittaker-Jones).</span>
                <span id="errfname2" class="error">*This can only contain alphabetic numbers and if desired, one hyphen</span>
           <br>
           <br>
           <label for="sname">Surname:</label>
            <input name="sname" id="sname" class="formfield" type="text">
            <span id="errsname" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="errsname1" class="error">*Name fields must have more than one character, and do not contain numbers
                or other non-allowed alphabetic characters. The only character the last name
                field should legitimately contain is a hyphen (e.g. Whittaker-Jones).</span>
            <span id="errsname2" class="error">*This can only contain alphabetic numbers and if desired, one hyphen</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="title">Title: </label>
              <select name="title" id="title">
                <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                <option value="Miss.">Miss.</option>
                <option value="Master.">Master.</option>
              </select>
             <span id="errtitle" class="error">*This is required</span>
           <br>
           <br>
           <br>
           <label for="HANo">Health Authority Number:</label>
           <input name="HANo" id="HANo" class="formfield"type="text">
             <span id="errHANo" class="error">*This is required</span>
             <span id="errHANo2" class="error">*This must be in format ZHA123456 (ZHA followed by 6 numbers)</span>
           <br>
           <br>
           <br>
           <label for="email">Email:</label>
             <input name="email" id="email" class="formfield"type="text">
             <span id="erremail" class="error">*This is required</span>
             <span id="erremail2" class="error">*Please enter a valid email</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="telno">Telephone Number:</label>
                <input name="telno" id="telno" class="formfield" type="text">
                <span id="errtelno" class="error">* If a telephone number is entered, then it should contain only numbers, not
                letters, or other disallowed characters. A valid Zedland telephone number has
                11 digits (no spaces)</span> 
                <span id="errtelno1" class="error">*This must just be numbers</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="checkForm()">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function checkForm(){    
    var isValid = true;
    var errors=document.getElementsByClassName('error');
    for(var i=0;i<errors.length;i++){
        errors[i].style.display='none';
    }   

    if (document.getElementById("fname").value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById("errfname").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errfname").style.visibility = "visible";
        isValid = false; 
    }

    if (document.getElementById("fname").value.length < 2 ) {
        document.getElementById("errfname1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errfname1").style.visibility = "visible";
         isValid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("fname").value.length > 1) {
        checkFName();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("sname").value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById("errsname").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errsname").style.visibility = "visible";
         isValid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("sname").value.length < 2 ) {
        document.getElementById("errsname1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errsname1").style.visibility = "visible";
         isValid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("sname").value.length > 1) {
        checkSName();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("title").value == "Please select" ) {
        document.getElementById("errtitle").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errtitle").style.visibility = "visible";
         isValid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("HANo").value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById("errHANo").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errHANo").style.visibility = "visible";
         isValid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("HANo").value.length > 0) {
        if (checkHANo());
    }

    if (document.getElementById("email").value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById("erremail").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("erremail").style.visibility = "visible";
         isValid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("email").value.length > 0 ) { 
        if(checkEmail());
    }

    if (document.getElementById("telno").value.length != 11 ) { 
        document.getElementById("errtelno").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errtelno").style.visibility = "visible";
        isValid = false; 
    }

    if (document.getElementById("telno").value == /^\d+$/ ) {
        document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.visibility = "visible";
         isValid = false;
    }
return isValid;
}

function checkEmail(){
 var email = document.getElementById('email');
 var emailRegEx = /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;

if (!emailRegEx.test(email.value)) {
       document.getElementById("erremail2").style.display="inline";
       document.getElementById("erremail2").style.visibility = "visible";
       isValid = false;
}

}

function checkHANo(){
    var HANo = document.getElementById("HANo");
    var hanoRegEx = /[ZHA]\d{6}/;

    if (!hanoRegEx.test(HANo.value)) {
        document.getElementById("errHANo2").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errHANo2").style.visibility = "visible";
        isValid = false;
    }

}

function checkFName(){
var first = document.getElementById("fname");
var firstRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,40}$/;

if (!firstRegEx.test(first.value)){
    document.getElementById("errfname2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errfname2").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

}

function checkSName(){
    var sec = document.getElementById("sname");
    var secRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,40}$/;

    if (!secRegEx.test(sec.value)){
        document.getElementById("errsname2").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errsname2").style.visibility = "visible";
        isValid = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: better html layout/css will help

Comment: I thought the breaks would help in the html, is it possible to put each label in a defined size - using div or a "container" id in the html, and defining height in the css , so that it doesn't move? This is on the basis, validation has worked, so all the information gathering bit is working; i just want it to look a bit better.

Comment: Share your css too, would be easier to test because every error message has visibility by default.

Comment: it thought i tried this earlier...not sure why its worked this time?! But the <br> tags seem to have done the trick this time

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>RATool</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cfcss.css">
       <script src="cf.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> Zedland Health Authority </h1>
    <h2> Contact Form </h2>
        <fieldset>
        <br>  <!-- NEW BR TAG HERE -->
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input name="fname" id="fname" class="formfield" type="text">
            <span id="errfname" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="errfname1" class="error">*Name fields must have more than one character, and do not contain numbers
                    or other non-allowed alphabetic characters. The only character the last name
                    field should legitimately contain is a hyphen (e.g. Whittaker-Jones).</span>
            <span id="errfname2" class="error">*This can only contain alphabetic numbers and one hyphen</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="sname">Surname:</label>
            <input name="sname" id="sname" class="formfield" type="text">
            <span id="errsname" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="errsname1" class="error">*Name fields must have more than one character, and do not contain numbers
                or other non-allowed alphabetic characters. The only character the last name
                field should legitimately contain is a hyphen (e.g. Whittaker-Jones).</span>
            <span id="errsname2" class="error">*This can only contain alphabetic numbers and one hyphen</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="title">Title: </label>
              <select name="title" id="title">
                <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                <option value="Miss.">Miss.</option>
                <option value="Master.">Master.</option>
              </select>
             <span id="errtitle" class="error">*This is required</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!-- BR TAG HERE -->
        <label for="HANo">Health Authority Number:</label>
        <input name="HANo" id="HANo" class="formfield"type="text">
            <span id="errHANo" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="errHANo2" class="error">*This must be in format ZHA123456 (ZHA followed by 6 numbers)</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!-- BR TAG HERE -->
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input name="email" id="email" class="formfield"type="text">
            <span id="erremail" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="erremail2" class="error">*Please enter a valid email</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!-- BR TAG HERE -->
        <label for="telno">Telephone Number:</label>
            <input name="telno" id="telno" class="formfield" type="text">
            <span id="errtelno" class="error">* If a telephone number is entered, then it should contain only numbers, not
                letters, or other disallowed characters. A valid Zedland telephone number has
                11 digits (no spaces)</span> 
            <span id="errtelno1" class="error">*This must just be numbers</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="checkForm()">Submit</button>
            <br> <!-- NEW BR TAG HERE -->
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```